# Cannot move area light pivot

Tags: rendering, light

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfEyhPXsOCM

this question is about :
        The 3D Cursor: 20:42
        Parenting an Area Light to a Path: 21:54
part if the above youtube video
In this YouTube video the guy is able to set the area light pivot Point to the world origin. However when I do it the yellow ball for the light pivot does not move. And when I rotate / move the area light the light beam does not stay pinned to the eyeball. Furthermore, when I parent the light area to the Circle and then I try to move my time bar that area light does not rotate a round the circle. In fact it does not move at all. I did a parent By follow path but it does not move it all.

Also after I parented them together, and I click on adjust last operation, it shows me the operation I did before  I parented them. so idk what that is about ...

I have tried in both render mode and material preview mode but it does not work[image]

**update** Picture: 
My  Make Parent looks completely different from his:
[image]

Comment: Use an empty see: [Have a lamp rotate around a fixed spot](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66130/have-a-lamp-rotate-around-a-fixed-spot/66144#66144)

Comment: I am not sure it is possible to explain it any better than in that video, just watch it a few more times until you get it.

Comment: @ cegaton, I just downloaded Blender like 4 weeks ago, so I have the newest one. 2.81. I do not see an option for "Track to" constraint.

Comment: @ Martynas Ziemys  I watched it over and over, It just does not work. He says at the Beginning of the video that it took him a long time to make this video and that at the end of it blender had been updated. Plus I just downloaded blender like 4 weeks ago, I think something has changed since he recorded at part.

Comment: both Cegaton and Marynas Ziemys Please see my update.

Comment: Track to constraint is there. In the Add Object Constraint section...

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are having problems is because you added a **Mesh Circle** instead of a **Curve, Circle**. Look more closely at the video 20:05, where he **Add** > **Curve** > **Circle**

Thats not the same as a **Add** > **Mesh** > **Circle** !

See screenshot below :

[image]

In the **Outliner** it should say **BezierCircle**  :)

Comment: Thanks!!! you were right ...

Answer (score 0):

This is an isolated test case to allow you to see it work with a simple sphere:

1. Create a new sculpting project (this will give you a sphere primitive).
2. Switch to layout view.
3. Hit Keypad 7 for top view.
4. Select existing light and delete it. Press shift + 'a' and add an area light.
5. (In top view) Press g + x and move the light to the right of the sphere (where you want the rotation path to occur)
6. (In top view) Press r + y + 90 and this rotates the light to point at sphere.
7. Change viewport shading to rendered.
8. Make sure you have the light selected and press the Object Data Properties tab. Adjust the power until you see the appropriate amount of light cast on the sphere. (I had to change it to 1000 watts)
9. (In top view) Press Shift + a and choose Curve -> Circle. Then press 's' and resize it to the path that intersects with your light.
10. Select the light. Then hold down Shift and select the curve. Now press Ctrl + p and select 'follow path'.
11. Now select the blue cursor and drag it to see the light rotate around the sphere.

When we begin using Blender sometimes we inadvertently do something that prevents other things from happening. It very difficult to know what you did that is preventing this part of the tutorial to work but this test case should allow to see that these steps in this tutorial do work if no mistakes were made up to that point.